# Having issue when reading binary data of float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module specifically to handle read/write binary files. I have an issue when reading values of data type that takes more than 1 byte such as `int64`, `float32`, ... etc. To illustrate my issue, let's see the following example I wrote. I generate random values of type `np.float64` which is `8` byte each:

```
# Write
n = 10
dim = 2
fd = os.open('test.dat', os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY)
data_w = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(n,dim)).astype(np.float64)
print("Written Data are:\n%s\n" % data_w)
os.write(fd, data_w.tobytes())
os.close(fd)
print("------------------ \n")

# Read
start_read = 0  # 0 for now. Later I can read from any row!
total_num_to_read = n*dim
fd = os.open('test.dat', os.O_RDONLY)
os.lseek(fd, start_read, 0)  # start_read from the beginning 0
raw_data = os.read(fd, total_num_to_read)  # How many values to be read
data_r = np.fromiter(raw_data, dtype=np.float64).reshape(-1, dim)
print("Data Read are:\n%s\n" % data_r)
os.close(fd)
```

The reading is not correct. Look how it is returned:

```
Written Data are:
[[ 2.75763292  9.87883101]
 [ 1.73752327  9.9633879 ]
 [ 1.01616811  1.81174597]
 [ 9.93904659 10.6757686 ]
 [ 7.02452029  2.68652109]
 [ 5.29766028 11.15384409]
 [ 4.12499766 10.37214532]
 [11.75811252  3.30378401]
 [ 1.72738203  2.11228277]
 [ 7.7321937  11.64298051]]

------------------ 

Data Read are:
[[250.  87.]
 [227. 216.]
 [161.  15.]
 [  6.  64.]
 [162. 178.]
 [ 59.  35.]
 [246. 193.]
 [ 35.  64.]
 [218.  97.]
 [ 81.  50.]]
```

I cannot retrieve it correctly! I thought `np.fromiter(raw_data, dtype=np.float64).reshape(-1, dim)` is supposed to take care of it but I don't know where the issue is. How can I read binary data in this case given that I know it is of particular data type (i.e., `np.float64`)?

Comment: _"I want to use os module specifically..."_ Just out of curiosity, why `os` 'specifically'? Why not use `numpy`'s built-in methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `np.fromstring(raw_data)` instead of `fromiter()`. Check documentation for the purpose of each function. In addition, when reading from file, read the correct **number of *bytes*!!!**: `8* total_num_to_read`.

```
In [103]: # Write
     ...: n = 10
     ...: dim = 2
     ...: fd = os.open('test.dat', os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY)
     ...: data_w = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(n,dim)).astype(np.float64)
     ...: print("Written Data are:\n%s\n" % data_w)
     ...: os.write(fd, data_w.tobytes())
     ...: os.close(fd)
     ...: print("------------------ \n")
     ...: 
     ...: # Read
     ...: start_read = 0  # 0 for now. Later I can read from any row!
     ...: total_num_to_read = n*dim
     ...: fd = os.open('test.dat', os.O_RDONLY)
     ...: os.lseek(fd, start_read, 0)  # start_read from the beginning 0
     ...: raw_data = os.read(fd, 8*total_num_to_read)  # How many values to be read
     ...: data_r = np.fromstring(raw_data, dtype=np.float64).reshape(-1, dim)
     ...: print("Data Read are:\n%s\n" % data_r)
     ...: os.close(fd)
     ...: 
     ...: 
Written Data are:
[[ 11.2465988    5.45304778]
 [ 12.06466331   9.95717255]
 [  7.35402895   1.68972606]
 [  0.7259652    1.01265826]
 [  3.11340311   2.44725153]
 [  2.82109715   5.02768335]
 [ 12.69054614   9.26028537]
 [  5.13785639   2.0780649 ]
 [  4.6796513    4.24710598]
 [  2.34859141   8.87224674]]

------------------ 

Data Read are:
[[ 11.2465988    5.45304778]
 [ 12.06466331   9.95717255]
 [  7.35402895   1.68972606]
 [  0.7259652    1.01265826]
 [  3.11340311   2.44725153]
 [  2.82109715   5.02768335]
 [ 12.69054614   9.26028537]
 [  5.13785639   2.0780649 ]
 [  4.6796513    4.24710598]
 [  2.34859141   8.87224674]]
```